# how do i stop a subscription in flow-router

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

I am trying to load different 3rd party data based on the params on a route.  The route doesn't change, just the param being send to it.

I need to stop the subscription that is pulling in the data, clear the data, then send a new api request to populate the subscription.

I'm using react-meteor with FlowRouter (and it works great!)

-- view.jsx --

```
View = ReactMeteor.createClass({
    getMeteorState: function(){
        return {
            feed: Feed.find().fetch()
        }
    },

    render: function(){
        return (
             {this.state.feed.map(function(post, i){
                 return <ViewPost data={post} key={i} />
             })}
        )
    }

})
```

-- menu-list-item.jsx --

```
MenuListItem = ReactMeteor.createClass({
    stopFeedSubscription: function(){
        FlowRouter.stop('feedSub')
        Feed.remove({})
    },

    render: function(){
        var route = "//view/"+this.props.data._id
        return (
                <li key={this.props.data._id} className="collection-item" data-post={this.props.data.name}>
                    <a href="#" data-route={route} className="btn-post-list" onClick={this.stopFeedSubscription}>{this.props.data.name}</a>
                </li>
            )
    }
})
```

When there is a click on the menu item, I want to stop any incoming data to that subscription and remove everything from it.  When the /view/:id is re-rendered, a new call to the 3rd party api happens and it grabs new data.

All of this works except that if data is still coming in when a menu item is clicked, it shows up in the new route which is supposed to display different data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flow Router does not have a way to stop subscriptions. We may don't have it too. If you need some something like, try to manage subscriptions within the React Components.

May be we can you can use [SubsManager](https://github.com/meteorhacks/subs-manager). Anyway, not sure that's what you need.

**There's a way to do this in the Router level too.**

Try to define subscription in the router by getting the param. So, when you need to stop it, move your app into a different route. Then your previous, subscription get stopped automatically.

By default, only the subscriptions which are defined on the current route is active. When changing routes, previous routes will get deactivated.

Comment: I'll check out SubsManager.  Either way, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Thanks -- seems like a core insight of FlowRouter is that proliferation of routes is no big deal.